# Plone: creating and using document tags?

Tags: search, tags, plone, doi

For an academic plone site I am creating, it is desirable to support document tags (see below).

There are multiple users for this site, and each user has a (long) list of publications that they alone can add / edit.

In its simplest form, a publication entry consists of a hyperlink or even just plain text. For instance:

1. A. Baynes, J. Watson and S. Holmes, "The role of observation and deduction in forensics", Applied Crime Solving, 221, 210-243 (1901). doi: 10.1032/acsolv2714

(The above is a fictitious article, but it has all the elements one expects in most citations.)

For those unfamiliar with DOI links, these are fixed text strings that can be resolved to the page for the article in question using dx.doi.org. Further, copyright / license terms often prohibit the authors from providing a full PDF / HTML for their articles on their websites. The articles often lie behind a paywall (usually accessible from most Universities / major research labs). So, running full text searches on the article itself is NOT an option.

Returning to the problem definition, I am assuming that the users will add their publications as links, but I want to give them the ability to specify a comma separated list of words / phrases (or tags) that more closely identify what the article is about.

For the above article, an appropriate list of tags would be:

forensics, haemoglobin, degradation of evidence

After each user appends such tags to the article, I want to create a backend that will allow visitors to the site to simply be able to enter these tags in a search field and find all publications that pertain to, say, haemoglobin.

That search should pull all publications that list haemoglobin as a tag, for all users of the site.

I intentionally used haemoglobin as a tag to illustrate that relevant tags need not be (and usually aren't) part of the text specified in the title of the article.

Further, the Plone "Collections" feature is not an adequate solution to this problem. Collections are typically generated by the admin. That means that a) admin intervention for something like this is essential and b) tags are best defined by users, not the admin.

Answer (score 0):

When adding any content type (File, Folder, Page, Link, Collection, ...) in Plone, you can apply any number of tags to the content.  This is done in the "Categorization" tab when editing/creating the content.

Visitors/Users can search the site based on tags like normal searches (using the search box or accessing the `/@@search` URL).

Moreover you can use "tag cloud" portlets to visualise the tags' frequencies.  Check the followings to get an idea:
 1. [A tag cloud portlet that rotates tags in 3D using a Flash movie](http://plone.org/products/quintagroup.portlet.cumulus)
 2. [TagCloud](http://plone.org/products/tagcloud)

*Don't forget to check [Plone documentation](http://plone.org/documentation), and specially [Plone user manual](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual) to get yourself acquainted with the way Plone works.*

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. I won't be using the tag cloud but can I additionally create collections that users can add to?

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Let us say I create collections 1-10. When adding a publication, the user should be able to specify which collection they (may) want to add it to.

Comment: Collections are effectively pre-configured searches. You may set them up to match your tags and the addition sot the results will be automatic.

Comment: As SteveM mentioned, Plone "collections" are not meant for that.  From what I could understand, you're thinking about a place to put the publications in; and if that's the case you can easily use a "folder" for that purpose.

Comment: No. I wasn't thinking of using a folder for this purpose. But use of tags will hopefully be good enough.

Comment: Thanks, SteveM. I guess I will simply have to rely on users choosing their tags with extra care.

Answer (score 0):

@user2751530

I would like to know whether you are still working on this specific project - I am currently developing a similar one using plone v4, documentviewer v3 and an as of yet nonexistant frontend. I would like to discuss different approaches to the tagging-by-user problem, you can contact me through skype (dawitt19) or twitter (pref.) through @japhigu.

Comment: I am working on that but it has taken a backseat for the past month or so. I would love to discuss these alternate approaches. But let us keep it on stackexchange. That way, it would be useful to have a reference and a solution if we come up with one.